# Highlight and remove values that do not duplicate

Tags: excel, duplicates, pivot-table

I am working with a large dataset in Excel, essentially what I want to do is to remove only values that do not appear in another column.

For example, I have two columns below:

| Name |
| --- |
| Max |
| Max |
| Max |
| John |
| John |
| Peter |
| Paul |
| Paul |
| Remy |
| Remy |

| Name2 |
| --- |
| Max |
| John |
| Remy |

So in this case, I want to highlight and remove all the entries for `Peter` and `Paul` since they do not appear in `Name2`

How would I go about doing this in Excel?

I was trying to using `COUNTIFS` but I am not sure

Would really appreciate some help, really want to learn Excel

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

To highlight those cells you could use Conditional formatting:

[image]

Or you create a helper column and use the filter function:

`=ISERROR(MATCH(D4:D13,B4:B6,0))`

For the deletion part you need VBA. I am pretty sure you will find answers on SO searching for "delete rows autofilter"